# Cannot make it work to get many to many related table by custom pivot table in laravel5.6

Tags: php, database, wordpress, laravel, relational-database

My Post model has this function not working

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = "wp_posts";
    protected $primaryKey = "ID";

    public function taxonomies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\TermTaxonomy', 'wp_term_relationships', 'object_id', 'term_taxonomy_id');
    }
}
```

I wanna get the taxonomies data from post through pivot table but I can't.

I connected Laravel to my WP database and tried to get Taxonomies from Posts.

Posts and Taxonomies are many to many relationship with 'wp_term_relationships' pivot table.

post table has 'ID' primary key

taxonomy table has 'term_taxonomy_id' primary key

The pivot table is like
'wp_term_relationships'
- 'object_id' ... related to Post.ID
- 'term_taxonomy_id' ... related to Taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id

I don't know why this not working. If anyone knows plz help me. Thank you so much.

### Add

```
// Taxonomy
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TermTaxonomy extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'wp_term_taxonomy';
    protected $primaryKey = 'term_taxonomy_id';
}

// in the Controller
public function profile($id)
{
    $teacher = User::isTeacher()->where(['ID' => $id])->with(['posts' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('post_type', 'answer')->take(3);
    }])->firstOrFail();

    $data = [
        'teacher' => $teacher
    ];

    return view('teacher.profile', $data);
}

// in the View
@foreach($teacher->posts as $answer) 
    @php 
    foreach($answer->postParent->taxonomies as $taxonomy) { 
        print($taxonomy->term_id); 
    } 
    @endphp 
@endforeach
```

Comment: add  `protected $primaryKey = "term_taxonomy_id";` in your `Taxonomy` model

Comment: Oh thanks that was also the point but I already did it

Comment: The sql is weird when I try to get the data `select `wp_term_taxonomy`.*, `wp_term_relationships`.`object_id` as `pivot_object_id`, `wp_term_relationships`.`term_taxonomy_id` as `pivot_term_taxonomy_id` from `wp_term_taxonomy` inner join `wp_term_relationships` on `wp_term_taxonomy`.`term_taxonomy_id` = `wp_term_relationships`.`term_taxonomy_id` where `wp_term_relationships`.`object_id` = '83'`   here the actual object_id is 82, but it's 83 here

Comment: I think inner join is working well but getting the data from joined table is not working

Comment: post your `Taxonomy` model class  and the code that you have used to fetch it

Comment: @rkj I edited my post and add those, thank you.

Comment: use `$answer->taxonomies` instead `$answer->postParent->taxonomies` in view

Comment: I tried now and it's the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174662/discussion-between-rkj-and-hanachan1026).

Comment: Try the relationship without `->take(3)`.

Comment: Thank you but I tried and still not working @JonasStaudenmeir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was not how to define many to many relationship,
it was how to retreive the relation data.

```
public function profile($id)
{
    $teacher = User::isTeacher()->where(['ID' => $id])->with(['posts' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('post_type', 'answer')->take(3)->with(['postParent' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('post_type', 'question')->with(['taxonomies' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('taxonomy', 'question_category')->with(['term']);
            }]);
        }]);
    }])->firstOrFail();

    $data = [
        'teacher' => $teacher
    ];

    return view('teacher.profile', $data);
}
```